# React Navigation - Listen parent action in child component

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation, react-navigation

I have a tab navigator Screen in which there are 2 tabs. The parent Stack has button in the header, which should work differntly w.r.t Two different screens/Tabs.

[image]

Now, What I have done is -

```js
navigation.setOptions({
  headerRight: () => (
    <TouchableOpacity>
      <Text>Update</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  ),
});
```

How I can handle the click of `Save` button from both the components under Tabs Navigator?

*Note* - I am using `react-navigation@v6`

Comment: Have a handler outside the scope of both screens to handle save action. It could be with a context provider wrapped around the screens. Using tools like the react context API, redux, or react-query. That way isolate your navigation logic from app operations.

Comment: Hi @iamcastelli - A small code snippet will really help me. Could you please provide ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, I want to give the answer of my question myself.

The solution is to not set the Navigation right button from Parent navigator, Access the parent navigation from each Tab screen and set the Right header.

Also you should use `useFocusEffect` to add this because it can be different for different tabs of the navigator. Here's how you can do it -

```js
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';

useFocusEffect(() => {
    navigation.getParent().setOptions({
      headerRight: () => (
        <TouchableOpacity 
          disabled={true}
          style={styles.headerRight}>
          <Text style={{ color: 'black' }}>Save</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ),
    });
});
```